# Appending string to elements in a bash array, but not if the array is empty

Tags: bash

I want to attach a string to each of the elements in an array in bash, but not if the array is empty.

Currently this works for non-empty arrays:

```
$ cat this.sh
#!/bin/bash
lst=$@
lst[0]="a"
lst[1]="b"
echo ${lst[@]/%/.ext}
$ bash this.sh
a.ext b.ext
```

But it fails for an empty array:

```
$cat that.sh 
#!/bin/bash
lst=$@
echo ${lst[@]/%/.ext}
$ bash that.sh 
.ext
```

So this fails, as I want the string to be empty, if the array is empty.

**Restriction:** I can't use an if-statement or loop constructs in this particular situation.

Comment: Can you use tests without `if`? eg `[ ${#lst} -gt 0 ] && echo ${lst[@]/%/.ext}` Incidentally, your `lst` variable isn't initially an array, just a string containing all the positional parameters.

Comment: @JoshJolly: no, unfortunately I can't use this.

Comment: How is your program supposed to do something under a certain condition if you dont test for the condition ? Are you allowed to use awk or sed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a slight misunderstanding in your OP. In your second example, `lst` is *not* an empty array. Check this out: add the line `declare -p lst` at the end of your script (the `declare` builtin used with the `-p` option will print out the information about the given variable):

```
#!/bin/bash
lst=$@
declare -p lst
```

then run your script:

```
$ ./myscript
declare -- lst=""
```

So for Bash, your `lst` is just an empty string (yet it is set). Look what an empty array is:

```
$ a=()
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='()'
```

and look what happens if I run your echo command:

```
$ echo ${a[@]/%/.ext}

$
```

did you see that? it's really empty!

I want to say that it really hurt me when I wrote `echo ${a[@]/%/.ext}` without quotes! the proper way would be:

```
$ echo "${a[@]/%/.ext}"

$
```

(still empty, eh).

Now you probably mean:

```
#!/bin/bash
lst=( "$@" )
echo "${lst[@]/%/.ext}"
```

I called this script `banana`, I `chmod +x banana` and I played with it:

```
$ ./banana

$ ./banana one two
one.ext two.ext
$ ./banana "one one" two
one one.ext two.ext
$ ./banana one ""
one.ext .ext
```

Answer (score 2):

In your second case, `lst` isn't an empty array: it's just an empty string. Ensure that `lst` is an array by using

```
ls=( "$@" )
```

In your first case, `lst` is an array because you ignore the initial assignment to `lst` by overwriting it with the following indexed assignments.